# How do I change the filename of the Junit XML report that Nightwatch.js generates?

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have a Nightwatch.js test suite running. When it completes, I've configured the output directory using the [output_folder setting](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/gettingstarted/configuration/config-test-settings.md). It produces JUnit XML files in that directory correctly. I have an existing automation tool which scans the directory for JUnit test XML files and reports on them. Unfortunately it only matches files in the directory with a naming scheme: TEST-.xml. Let's assume that I can't change the matching rules on my automation tool. I'm looking for a way to add "TEST-" as a prefix to my tests. Ideally I can do this by configuring Nightwatch. Does Nightwatch support this configuration? I can't find any such options.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my test scripts in package.json so that they did a rename after the test was run. Here is what they were before:

```
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "integ-tests": "<some nightwatch command>"
    }
    // ...
}
```

Here is what they were after:

```
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "rename-integ-tests": "node -e \"require('fs').readdir('<my test directory>', (err, files) => { files.forEach(file => { if(file.endsWith('.xml') && ! file.startsWith('TEST-')) { fs.rename('<my test directory>' + file, '<my test directory>/TEST-' + file, function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); console.log('Renamed Smoke Test: ' + file + ' to TEST-' + file) }) } }); });\"",
        "private-integ-tests": "<some nightwatch command>",
        "integ-tests": "npm run private-integ-tests && npm run rename-integ-tests"
    }
    // ...
}
```